# How can I build entire project structure with babel cli

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have a complete project structure(in node) with most of my codes in `src/` folder and some helper functions in `helper/` folder both are sitting in the project root directory and I had to use

```
"babel src -d public/src  && babel helper -d public/helper && babel index -d public/index -w"
```

in order to preserve the import and export folder structure when babel finishes the tranpilling. Is there an easier way to do this?

I have read about babel and gain some knowledge but all the tutorials i see doesn't involve this kind of scenario.

The folder project structure is preserve this way and everything works well in node though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
babel public/folder1 public/folder2 public/folder3 ... -d -w
```

Or using wildcard:

```
babel public/** -d -w
```